# What is the running time complexity of this for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

```
for (int p = t; p > 0; p >>= 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - p; ++i) {
        if ((i & p) != 0) {
            sort2(a, i, i+p);
        }
    }
    for(int q = t; q > p; q >>= 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n- q; ++i) {
            if ((i & p) != 0) {
                sort2(a, i+p, i+q);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here `n` is some positive integer and `t` is greater than `n/2`, but not equal to `n`.

As per my understanding, the inner for loop runs for `(n-p)` times but I could not figure out the outer for loop.

I tried finding it as below:

If `t=64` and `n=100`, it takes the binary value of `p` which is equal to `64` and so `p=1000000` **base 2**.

I understand that every time it reduces by one digit and it executes a total of 7 times in this case. I somehow couldn't figure out general time.

Also, my understanding is that the 3rd for loop i.e

`for(int q = t; q > p; q >>= 1)`

doesn't execute at all because the condition `q>p` doesn't satisfy as `p=q=t`.

Is this correct? I am just starting out with algorithms.

Comment: There are more opening braces than closing braces and the indentation is not helpful.

Comment: What is `sort2`?

Answer (score 0):

For this: Complexity would be `BigO( log(t)(n-t)log(t) )`

Excluding the `sort2` function complexity inside the `for` loop.

**Explaination:**

- Outer loop Complexity would be `log(p)+1` [Each time it is right shifting the bit by 1 and going for `greater than 0`], so for t = 64, the loop will go as [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1].
- Inner loop complexity is going to be `greater of ( O(n-p), O((n-t)log(t)) )`

**Execution**

for the second inner loop having nested for loop with the most outer loop:

[image]

Comment: My understanding is there is one more for loop for(int q = t; q > p; q >>= 1), So, this for loop is (n-t)log(t) and the final outer for loop is again log(t), so the overall complexity would be (n-t)(log(t))^2. Please correct me.

Comment: you have 2 inner loop, and both of these two are not nested, so at the end they would get added not would be multiplied.

Comment: Yes @Sree your right, I haven't seen the inner nested for. I guess you have edited your code. I have changed the answer

Comment: How can you answer without knowing the complexity of `sort2` ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Buddy, we have to just answer the `for` loop complexity, if you observe the question properly.

Comment: @Nityanarayan44: Mr Nityanarayan44, there are four loops in this code and the complexity of all of them depends on the complexity of `sort2`, if you observe properly.